# Multi-threading Issue - Passing objects between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, lwjgl, packet

I'm currently trying to make a really simple multiplayer game in java (with OpenGL (LWJGL)) and currently the program runs on two different threads.

Thread 1: Runs all the game logic and rendering

Thread 2: Handles the connection between server and client

So basically thread 2 sits and wait for incoming packets and whenever it receives a login-packet I want it to create a player-object but it seems like the new object is created on thread 2 and that causes the following error when trying to render:

**Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No GLCapabilities instance has been set for the current thread.**

I'm fairly new to both OpenGL and multi-threading and there is probably a pretty straightforward and easy solution to this but I'm wondering how I can create an object when receiving the packet and add it to thread 1.

Thread 2:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
        }
    }
```

parsePacket() checks the type of the packet and if it's a login-packet it will call the following method:

```
public void addPlayerToGame(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
    Packet00Login packet = new Packet00Login(data);

    level.addObject(new PlayerMP(packet.getUsername(), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), address, port));
}
```

The addObject method simply adds the objects to an arraylist.

```
public void addObject(GameObject o) {
    this.objects.add(o);
}
```

All objects are then being rendered with this call on thread 1:

```
public void render() {
    for (GameObject o : objects) {
        o.render();
    }
    player.render();
}
```

Comment: Show (at least) the constructor of `PlayerMP` and the relevant parts of the stack trace. Likely, you are doing GL-operations in the constructor, and this happens on the wrong thread. The solution could then be to handle the information that is required for creating the player to the GL thread, and let the GL thread actually create the player.

Comment: @Marco13 Yes I was calling GL-operations in the constructor! I moved all those operations into a "prepare"-method which I call right before adding the object into the list (on the GL-thread) and now it works! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't modify your GameObject list from the second thread since changes are extremely high you will be iterating on that list in the first thread. Which would cause a current modification exception. Or worse, creating undefined behaviors with openGL.

What you have to do is having a task list on your first thread. Every loop, you execute all tasks in the task list then clear it.

So instead of directly adding an game object to the list, add a task to add the object.

(Also, make sure to make the execution of the tasks thread safe)

Comment: I made a separate array-list in which I add all the things that should be added and then iterate through it! Works like a charm, thanks! :)

Comment: In my opinion, you should have a task list anyway. Since you will probably have to update objects the current list at some point (like when a player is moving) and having an other list won't help you with that. Also, don't forget to validate the answer

Comment: Ah that's true! I have never done anything like this before and I appreciate all the help I can get. I'll definitely look into it, thanks :)